# gomoku AI algorithm

Tags: algorithm, gomoku

The gomoku AI algorithms that I could find has 'weight's so the AI can found where the most appropriate place is.

However, I could not figure out even what the 'weight' is, and also how to get the weight.

Does anyone can explain to me what the weight is and how to get it?

Comment: My guess is that you are looking at a neural network algorithm. You could get weights by training the model or, if you are lucky, weights of a pre-trained model may have been made available by someone.

Comment: @Reuben.L I was looking for the non-ML-like algorithm, so it should not be such thing like that. The 'weight' I found was defined around the go pieces and the new piece is placed at where it has one of the biggest 'weight's. (Sorry for my bad English.)